# Iteratively apply function to its result without generating a seq

Tags: clojure

This is one of those "Is there a built-in/better/idiomatic/clever way to do this?" questions.

I want a function--call it `fn-pow`--that will apply a function f to the result of applying f to an argument, then apply it to the result of applying it to its result, etc., `n` times.  For example,

```
(fn-pow inc 0 3)
```

would be equivalent to

```
(inc (inc (inc 0)))
```

It's easy to do this with `iterate`:

```
(defn fn-pow-0
  [f x n]
  (nth (iterate f x) n))
```

but that creates and throws away an unnecessary lazy sequence.

It's not hard to write the function from scratch.  Here is one version:

```
(defn fn-pow-1
  [f x n]
  (if (> n 0) 
    (recur f (f x) (dec n))
    x))
```

I found this to be almost twice as fast as `fn-pow-0`, using Criterium on `(fn-pow inc 0 10000000)`.

I don't consider the definition of `fn-pow-1` to be unidiomatic, but `fn-pow` seems like something that might be a standard built-in function, or there may be some simple way to define it with a couple of higher-order functions in a clever arrangement.  I haven't succeeded in discovering either.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I think you mean `(defn fn-pow-0 [f x n] (nth (iterate f x) n))`?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the kind of question that really has a "the answer" as such, and more than one of the answers given so far could reasonably be given that title.  I learned something from each of them.  I marked @A.Webb's answer as "the answer" because of the depth of its explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The built-in you are looking for is probably `dotimes`. I'll tell you why in a round-about fashion.

#### Time

What you are testing in your benchmark is mainly the overhead of a level of indirection. That `(nth (iterate ...) n)` is *only* twice as slow as what compiles to a loop when the body is a very fast function is rather surprising/encouraging. If `f` is a more costly function, the importance of that overhead diminishes. (Of course if your `f` is low-level and fast, then you *should* use a low-level loop construct.)

Say your function takes ~ 1 ms instead

```
(defn my-inc [x] (Thread/sleep 1) (inc x))
```

Then *both* of these will take about 1 second -- the difference is around 2% rather than 100%.

```
(bench (fn-pow-0 my-inc 0 1000))
(bench (fn-pow-1 my-inc 0 1000))
```

#### Space

The other concern is that `iterate` is creating an unnecessary sequence. But, if you are not holding onto the head, just doing an `nth`, then you aren't *really* creating a sequence *per se* but sequentially creating, using, and discarding `LazySeq` objects. In other words, you are using a constant amount of space, though generating garbage in proportion to `n`. However, unless your `f` is primitive or *mutating* its argument, then it is *already* producing garbage in proportion to `n` in producing its own intermediate results.

#### Reducing Garbage

An interesting compromise between `fn-pow-0` and `fn-pow-1` would be

```
(defn fn-pow-2 [f x n] (reduce (fn [x _] (f x)) x (range n)))
```

Since `range` objects know how to intelligently reduce themselves, this does not create *additional* garbage in proportion to `n`. It boils down to a loop as well. This is the `reduce` method of range:

```java
public Object reduce(IFn f, Object start) {
    Object ret = f.invoke(start,n);
    for(int x = n+1;x < end;x++)
            ret = f.invoke(ret, x);
    return ret;
}
```

This was actually the fastest of the three (before adding primitive type-hints on `n` in the `recur` version, that is) with the slowed down `my-inc`.

#### Mutation

If you are iterating a function potentially expensive in time or space, such as matrix operations, then you may very well be wanting to use (in a contained manner) an `f` that mutates its argument to eliminate the garbage overhead. Since mutation is a side effect, and you want that side effect `n` times, `dotimes` is the natural choice.

For the sake of example, I'll use an `atom` as a stand-in, but imagine bashing on a mutable matrix instead.

```
(def my-x (atom 0))

(defn my-inc! [x] (Thread/sleep 1) (swap! x inc))

(defn fn-pow-3! [f! x n] (dotimes [i n] (f! x)))
```

Comment: Very, *very* informative. Kplow! (head exploding. a little.) Had thought about `reduce` but it seemed silly at the time. But I'm surprised to find, after reading your answer, that for a fast operation (regular `inc`), the `reduce` version is a lot slower even than the no-type-hint `recur` version. Why? It's a loop in Java. (Thought about `dotimes`, but network settling with matrices really is very natural as a purely functional operation, and that's how I coded it. I may mutate matrices elsewhere, where weights in a network--i.e. matrix elements--have to change in a piecemeal fashion.)

Comment: @Mars For a very low-level function like `inc`, the `reduce` version should be about twice as slow. Is that what you saw? This is because we had to wrap `f` in another function `(fn [x _] ...)` to ignore the second argument. So there are two fast function invocations in place of just one. For a slower `f`, the overhead of the `(fn [x _] ...)` becomes negligible. Note: I've not seen this idiom used in the wild, so consider it mainly for illustrative purposes.

Comment: I see.  Cool.  The `reduce` version was 3X slower with `inc`, but that's on my slower machine.  It might be 2X on the faster machine: `fn-pow-0`, the `iterate` version, is 3X slower than `fn-pow-1` on the slow machine, but 2X slower on the fast one.  (My mileage does vary.)

Answer (score 3):

That sounds just like composing functions `n` times.

```
(defn fn-pow [f p t]
    ((apply comp (repeat t f)) p))
```

Comment: Nice idea, Ankur.  Even though pete23 is right--it seems to be slower in my tests, it can run out of heap space with large `t`.  Always good to have multiple methods to consider.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm. I note that Ankur's version is around 10x slower than your original - possibly not the intent, no matter how idiomatic? :-)

Type hinting fn-pow-1 simply for the counter yields substantially faster results for me - around 3x faster.

```
(defn fn-pow-3 [f x ^long n]
    (if (> n 0)
       (recur f (f x) (dec n))
        x))
```

This is around twice as slow as a version which uses inc directly, losing the variability (not hinting x to keep to the spirit of the test)...

```
(defn inc-pow [x ^long n]
    (if (> n 0)
       (recur (inc x) (dec n))
        x))
```

I think that for any nontrivial f that fn-pow-3 is probably the best solution.

I haven't found a particularly "idiomatic" way of doing this as it does not feel like common use case outside of micro benchmarks (although would love to be contradicted).

Would be intrigued to hear of a real world example, if you have one?

Comment: I have a neural network settling function using core.matrix, that's about 8 lines of code--i.e. not simple matrix multiplication. Settling the network means iteratively applying this function to its output. But apart from my particular use case, I'd think that this kind of iteration wouldn't be unusual. Any time someone uses `iterate`, they are doing something like this. All that's different is not saving intermediate steps. Surely I'm not alone. (Wow, big difference with the type hint. Don't know whether I can do that with matrices, but I'll wait until everything works before type hinting.)

Comment: Hmmm. This is the danger of microbenchmarking - as soon as f starts doing significant work beyond inc (doing something chunky with a matrix would do it), the overhead of all our optimisations here will become less of an issue and maybe become irrelevant. I think your approach of getting it right first is the right one, then maybe applying optimisation as guided by a profiler. If you're going to break abstraction, always best to do it for the important stuff.

Comment: I misunderstood the type hint in your defns.  I thought the hint went after the parameter--I thought you were specifying the type of `x`.  I don't see any reason why I shouldn't add a type hint on `n` now in a general-purpose `fn-pow`.  It won't make much difference with the iterative matrix operations, but I don't see how it can hurt.  (The settling function is part of a central routine called repeatedly.  More speed is beneficial.  My guess is that no one part will be a large bottleneck, so small optimizations that don't mangle the code may be worthwhile.)

Comment: Benchmarking with a realistic neural net for my program does indeed show no discernable speed difference due to the type hinting, btw, but still, can't hurt, and might help for something.

Answer (score 1):

To us benighted imperative programmers, a more general pattern is known as a *while* statement. We can capture it in a macro:

```
(defmacro while [bv ; binding vector
                 tf ; test form
                 recf ; recur form
                 retf ; return form
                 ]
  `(loop ~bv (if ~tf (recur ~@recf) ~retf)))
```

... in your case

```
(while [x 0, n 3] (pos? n)
  [(inc x) (dec n)]
  x)
; 3
```

---

- I was hoping to type-hint the `n`, but it's illegal. Maybe it's
  inferred.
- Forgive me (re)using [`while`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/while).
- This isn't quite right: it doesn't allow for computation prior to the recur-form.

---

We can adapt the macro to do things prior to the recur:

```
(defmacro while [bv ; binding vector
                 tf ; test form
                 bodyf ; body form
                 retf ; return form
                 ]
  (let [bodyf (vec bodyf)
        recf (peek bodyf)
        bodyf (seq (conj (pop bodyf) (cons `recur recf)))]
    `(loop ~bv (if ~tf ~bodyf ~retf))))
```

For example

```
(while [x 0, n 3] (pos? n)
  (let [x- (inc x) n- (dec n)] [x- n-])
  x)
; 3
```

I find this quite expressive. YMMV.

Comment: Thanks Thumbnail. I personally don't find it appealing, but: Let a thousand flowers bloom. It doesn't seem to me that the second definition is more efficient, though. Here are the `macroexpand-1`'s of the two versions: `(clojure.core/loop [x 0 n 3] (if (pos? n) (recur (inc x) (dec n)) x))` and `(clojure.core/loop [x 0 n 3] (if (pos? n) (let [x- (inc x) n- (dec n)] (recur x- n-)) x))`. Doesn't the `let` binding do the same thing as binding in the `recur` call? (You won't find me dissing imperative programming, btw. To every thing there is a season. And everybody creates side-effects sometimes.)

Comment: @Mars Just nipping the lion's tail :). I have found programming in Clojure quite a revelation. This macro just syntactically sweetens (or sours, according to taste) a repetitive pattern. On the one side, we have such a plethora of `if` variants, inflected by `not` and `let` and `when`. On the other we have all the sequence structures. I wonder that nothing has been done to capture simple *functional* repetition: the squeezed middle? This macro is my wee shot at it.