# Clojure: Executing an operation n times using the output as input of next operation (a-la reduce)

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, reduce

I want to execute a given amount of time a certain operation (e.g., generating a tribe). Each time I would like to use the output of the previous iteration as input of the next one.

I am achieving it by doing a dummy reduce on collection of n elements, I then consider only the accumulator and throw away the element from the collection.

```
(defn generate-game [world n-tribes]
  (let [ game (create-game world)
         game (reduce (fn [acc, _] (:game (generate-tribe acc))) game (repeat n-tribes :just_something))]
    game))
```

I assume there is a much better way to do that. Can you help me finding it?

Comment: Iterate is what I was looking for.
The final solution is slightly different because generate-tribe returns a map which contains the game (it contains also the generate tribe).

For me the final solution is:


```
(defn generate-game [world n-tribes]
  (let [ game (create-game world)
         game (nth (iterate #(:game (generate-tribe %)) game) n-tribes :just_something)]
    game))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method used in the question is fine, but use range instead

```
(defn generate-game [world n-tribes]
  (reduce (fn [acc _] (:game (generate-tribe acc)))
          (create-game world)
          (range n-tribes)))
```

Since range objects know how to intelligently reduce themselves, this will get turned into a loop. This is the `reduce` method of range:

```
public Object reduce(IFn f, Object start) {
    Object ret = f.invoke(start,n);
    for(int x = n+1;x < end;x++)
            ret = f.invoke(ret, x);
    return ret;
}
```

If your game state is going to wind up in an atom anyway then you could also consider `dotimes` to update it.

```
(defn generate-game [world n-tribes]
  (let [game (atom (create-game world))]
    (dotimes [_ n-tribes] (swap! game (comp :game generate-tribe)))
    game))
```

Iterate is also a fine solution. More discussion at [Iteratively apply function to its result without generating a seq](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23178750/1756702).

Answer (score 4):

If it's the same function repeated `n-tribes` times, then using [iterate](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/iterate) and getting the `n-tribes`'th element should work:

```
(defn generate-game [world n-tribes]
  (let [ game (create-game world)
         game (nth (iterate generate-tribe game) n-tribes)]
         game))
```

Remember that `iterate` creates a lazy sequence so nothing will be calculated until you request it.

Another option is applying [comp](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/comp) to the list of functions, after all it's a simple function composition:

```
 (generate-tribe (generate-tribe .... (generate-tribe game) ....))

                                 n-tribes times
```

So something like:

```
(defn generate-game [world n-tribes]
  (let [ game (create-game world)
         game ((apply comp (repeat n-tribes generate-tribe)) game)]
         game))
```

expresses exactly that idea.

Comment: better to use `->>` in let `game (->> (create-game world) (...))`

Comment: @edbond Correct me if I'm wrong, but threading macros won't work if the number of functions to thread through isn't known at read time. In the cases when it is known it's the cleanest solution.

Comment: just a syntax sugar. Will expand on compile time to the same forms.

Comment: @soulcheck in both your let blocks, the number of repetitions is a numeric parameter, which is as easily used by a threading macro as by a let macro. Instead of binding the same value repeatedly you can thread from one statement to the next.

Comment: @noisesmith ahh, ok you mean threading between forms inside `let`, not threading the multiple `generate-tribe` calls. Yeah, that would work, but it's just a syntax preference. I didn't change the way OP used `let` form, cause that wasn't really the issue here.

Answer (score 2):

Not a Clojure expert, but I would expect

```
(defn generate-game [world n-tribes]
    (nth (iterate generate-tribe (create-game world)) n-tribes))
```

or (less terse)

```
(defn generate-game [world n-tribes]
  (let [game (create-game world)]
    (nth (iterate generate-tribe game) n-tribes)))
```

to work